# how to selectively not use aliases defined in .bashrc

Tags: bash, alias

I have a number of aliases defined in my **.bashrc**. E.g:

```
    alias ls='ls -la --color'
```

The thing is that sometimes I want to selectively **not use** the expansion. E.g. so that I can do a:

```
ls -a
```

One solution I've found is to do a:

```
`which ls` -a
```

when I want to **not** use the alias. But I am wondering if there is another established idiom for doing that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape the command used as an alias.

```
\ls -a
```

Comment: also `'ls'` or `""ls` or `l''s` or `l"s"`, etc. but the backslash is the least typing.  (You can change it up by doing `l\s` instead of `\ls`, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Use the *command* builtin. The Bash manual describes this builtin as follows:

> Run command with args suppressing the normal shell function lookup. Only builtin commands or commands found in the PATH are executed.

Comment: `command` is useful if you have a function overriding a standard command, which quoting won't help with. But it's rather a lot of extra typing just to bypass an alias.